# SharePoint and Firefox 3

Tags: sharepoint, firefox, moss, firefox-3

I think most of the SharePoint developers and administrators know that with the change form Firefox 2 to Firefox 3 some functionality of SharePoint have became unavailable.

Especially adding Webparts to a site and using the PeoplePicker don't work anymore with Firefox 3. So I want to know how you deal with this problem when some of your users are complaining about having to use the IE to get the same functionality as with Firefox 2.

It's quite plain to me that it is not possible to get the full functionality with Firefox but it would be great to get at least the same with Firefox 3 as you got before with Firefox 2.

Or are there any workarounds to get Firefox 3 working with SharePoint properly?

Answer (score 3):

I am using IE Tab: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be the fact that whenever a pop-up windows opens during a SharePoint action, like adding a webpart to a site, the information or data form the pop-up windows is not transmitted to the initial window which opened the pop-up window.

Answer (score 0):

What underlying code is it trying to run that Firefox 3 won't support?

Is it just using a bad agent sniffer? that can't handle v3?

The only thing I've encountered in v3 that isn't handled as nice as v2, is the ability to call .focus() on non-form elements.  It worked better in v2, v3 seems to have some issues.

Answer (score 0):

The [official announcement of Service Pack 2 for WSS 3.0 and MOSS 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/04/15/service-pack-2-for-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-and-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-due-to-ship-april-28th.aspx)  contains the following text:

> Also with the new service pack,
>   Internet Explorer 8 will be added into
>   browser support matrix as level one,
>   and Firefox 2.0 and **3.0** as level two.

So maybe an upgrade to SharePoint SP2 will fix your problems? More details on SP2 are scheduled for release next week.

Comment: Oh great! I'm looking forward to the release.